# Spread props from multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm creating a component that have 2 other components inside. I would like to spread props for both of them so I'm able to use props for each one of them. How can I direct the `style` prop? i.e

```
import FirstComponent from '../components'
import SecondComponent from '../components'

function SimpleButton (props) {
  return (
    <FirstComponent
      {...props}
    >
      <SecondComponent
        {...props}
      />
    </FirstComponent>
  )
}

function HomeScreen () {
  return (
    <SimpleButton
      style={this is the style for FirstComponent}
      style={this is the style for SecondComponent}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: `<SimpleButton firstStyle="..." secondStyle="..." />` and in the code `return <FirstComponent {...props.firstStyle } /><SecondComponent {...props.secondStyle } />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename keys:

```
function SimpleButton (props) {
  return (
    <FirstComponent
      {...props, style: props.firstComponentStyle}
    >
      <SecondComponent
        {...props, style: props.firstComponentStyle}
      />
    </FirstComponent>
  )
}

function HomeScreen () {
  return (
    <SimpleButton
      firstComponentStyle={this is the style for FirstComponent}
      secondComponentStyle={this is the style for SecondComponent}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works

```
function SimpleButton (props) {
  return (
    <FirstComponent
      style={props.FirstComponentStyle}
      {...props}
    >
      <SecondComponent
        style={props.SecondComponentStyle}
        {...props}
      />
    </FirstComponent>
  )
}

function HomeScreen () {
  return (
    <SimpleButton
      FirstComponentStyle={this is the style for FirstComponent}
      SecondComponentStyle={this is the style for SecondComponent}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend putting the style after the prop spread. Otherwise it will be immediately overwritten when you spread over it.

Comment: Thank you so much!